# Access sd card on a UWP windows phone emulator by clicking a button in an app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, uwp

I am in the process of making a Windows phone app and I would like to be able to add a button on my app that will allow me to access the virtual sd card on the emulator and be able to choose a txt file and read it within the app.
I am fairly new to all of this too.

Many thanks

Rob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Access sd card on a UWP windows phone emulator by clicking a button in an app

Firstly, ensure you have "Insert the SD card" by configuring the SD Card tab of the emulator's Additional Tools. So the SD card folder for emulator can be using. Details for how to configure please reference [SD card](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/test-with-the-emulator#sd-card) parts of [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/test-with-the-emulator#sd-card).

Secondly, specify the `removableStorage` capability in the app manifest file before your app can store and access files on the SD card. Typically you also have to register to handle the type of files that your app stores and accesses.For example, you need to visit the `txt` file in the SD card storage, configure the app manifest as follows:

```
<Applications>
...
    <Extensions>  
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
          <uap:FileTypeAssociation Name="camera_assoication">
            <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
              <uap:FileType>.bmp</uap:FileType>
              <uap:FileType>.txt</uap:FileType>
              <uap:FileType>.gif</uap:FileType>       
            </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
          </uap:FileTypeAssociation>
        </uap:Extension>
    </Extensions>
  </Application>
</Applications>
<Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="internetClient" />
  <uap:Capability Name="removableStorage" />
</Capabilities>
```

More details about capabilities please reference [App capability declarations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations).

At last, now you can follow the sample on [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/access-the-sd-card) to write your logic. For example, you want to read a txt file in the SD card, you can use code as follows:

XAML

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtreadresult"></TextBlock>
<Button x:Name="btnreadsd" Click="btnreadsd_Click" Content="read file from SD"></Button>
```

Code behind

```
private async void btnreadsd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   StorageFolder externalDevices = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;
   // Get the first child folder, which represents the SD card.
   StorageFolder sdCard = (await externalDevices.GetFoldersAsync()).FirstOrDefault();

   if (sdCard != null)
   {
       // An SD card is present and the sdCard variable now contains a reference to it.
       StorageFile txtfile = await sdCard.GetFileAsync("text.txt");          
       string testtext = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(txtfile);
       txtreadresult.Text = testtext;
   }
   else
   {
       // No SD card is present.
   }
}
```

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you very much for your answer its really helped.

Comment: @robbiedarza, please reference this [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). It will be benefit for you.